# How can I make every member in python array starts with zero?

Tags: python, arrays

How can I count down each member in ass until zero. Basically, every member should start with zero.

> `ass = [[8, 9],[0, 1, 2, 3],[3, 4, 5, 6, 7],[2, 3, 4, 9]]`

For example; `[8, 9]` should be `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`
But `[0, 1, 2, 3]` now starts from zero, I do not change anything

Thank you

Comment: the shown array can not be initialized. Use list

Comment: Do you mean count up from 0? Better show the complete expected result for `ass` (and maybe rename the variable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining `range` with remaining slice:

```
arr = [[8, 9],[0, 1, 2, 3],[3, 4, 5, 6, 7],[2, 3, 4, 9]]
arr = [list(range(0, a[0]+1)) + a[1:] for a in arr]
```

---

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [0, 1, 2, 3],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9]]
```